# Syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end arr.each_with_index |ele1, idx1|

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Get the following error when testing this method.

```
def opposite_count(nums)
pairs = []
    arr.each_with_index |ele1, idx1|
        arr.each_with_index |ele2, idx2|
            if (idx2 > idx1) && (ele1 + ele2 == 0)
              pairs << ele1
            end
        end 
    end
    return pairs.length
end
```

Goal is to take in an array of unique numbers and return the number of pairs of elements that sum to 0.

The other errors that show up are:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
        arr.each_with_index |ele2, idx2|
```

and

```
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing a `do` keyword after `each_with_index` for both loops.

Also, this would give you further error for `arr` not being defined.